# Find in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am trying to perform Login operation by checking the username and password are correct but the problem is if i check with find operation it just returns me the ID alone i want it to return the whole field for an instance if it is a match it should return me all the details of that particular user ex: username,email,password,DOB all the details. But my query returns only id. The query is

```
  db.users.find({"email":"cool1nn@gmail12.com"},{"pasword":"1345"})
```

And If i perform via Nodejs it returns the Id and Password alone

```
  userSchema.find({"email":req.body.email},{"password":req.body.pwd},function(err,item) {

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("item " + item);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for [find()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) is the query, the second argument is projection.

You are doing `userSchema.find(query, projection)` opposed to just `userSchema.find(query)`.

You want

```
userSchema.find({ email: "cool1nn@gmail12.com", pasword: "1345" })
```

Also since you are looking for ONE item, use [findOne()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) not `find()`.

```
userSchema.findOne({ email: "cool1nn@gmail12.com", pasword: "1345" })
```

Comment: Thanks allot Mikey a general query is it correct way for user login check i have heard like use PassportJS for verification

Comment: @kannan Two different things really. Your query only finds the user -- nothing more. [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) is for authentication (that will include finding the user).